# Parent class method

Tags: python

Im trying to write a simple setup to call a parent class @classmethod but getting error's...Please let me know what is the issue here?

```
class Parent(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print "Parent initialized"

        @classmethod    
        def resource_setup(cls):
            print "parent method"




class Child(Parent):
        def __init__(self):
            print "Child initialized"

        @classmethod    
        def childmethod(cls):
            super(Parent, cls).resource_setup()
            print "child method"


c = Child()            
Child().childmethod()
```

Output:

```
Child initialized
Child initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ANAND\workspace\Scratch\Scratch\Parent.py", line 30, in <module>
    Child().childmethod()
  File "C:\Users\ANAND\workspace\Scratch\Scratch\Parent.py", line 25, in childmethod
    super(Parent, cls).resource_setup()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'resource_setup'
```

Question:

```
1. When I create a child object c = Child(), I don't see the display of "parent initialized"..I expect the Parent class to be initialized.


2.How can I call the parent method @classmethod from the child @classmethod?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super(Child, cls)`.  The first argument to `super` should be the class whose superclass you want to call the method on, not the superclass itself.

Your question 1 is unrelated.  If you want the child `__init__` to call the parent `__init__`, you need to do so explicitly using `super`, just as you did with `parentmethod` and `childmethod`.  (That is, do `super(Child, self).__init__()` from within the child's `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

1. When I create a child object c = Child(), I don't see the display of "parent initialized"..I expect the Parent class to be initialized.

   A: In python, derived class's `__init__` does not call the base class's `__init__` implicitly, you need to call it explicitly. Not as the constructor in c++ do, which may cause a bit confuse if you are a c++ programer.
2. How can I call the parent method @classmethod from the child @classmethod?

   A: Use `super(Child, cls)` not `super(Parent, cls)`.